# MySQL Table Lock

Tags: mysql, locking

Do I need to explicitly lock mysql table for the following case:

mysql database user name : db_user (and is only one)
web client sessions : many users logged in simultaneously

As the mysql user is single, but I have many client sessions with my web server. what will happen (INSERT RECORD IN ONE TABLE THEN GET INSERT ID AND ADD DATA TO ANOTHER TABLE):

1. many web sessions have separate copy of db_user.
2. a single copy of db_user for many browser sessions.
3. any other.

Please help.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what, exactly, you are asking. If you are only SELECTing data, then no, you never need to LOCK tables.

Comment: when Inserting and subsequently adding data to other tables using last insert ID from first table.

Comment: What are the purposes of locking table? Do you want to allow inserts only for one user to get primary key? If it is true you can use InnoDB engine and and `last_insert_id()` function. This function is a session based function so will always get a unique value (in the different sessions). InnoDb engine will allow you use row level locking insted of table locking so the other connections will be working too

Answer (score 4):

Harmeet,

The short answer is no, you do not need to use `LOCK TABLES` when doing what you describe.

You only need to use `LOCK TABLES` when you want to be assured that you are the only one writing to a table, for example, if you want to `INSERT` a large number of records, and want the operation to occur as fast as possible.

You can see this in the dump files created by the `mysqldump` command. Here's an example from a dump file:

```
LOCK TABLES `tbl` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tbl` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `tbl` VALUES ...
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tbl` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: would locking be beneficial for one single (but huge) REPLACE statement?